# Confusion Over Versions of JRE Available in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse

I just installed JDK 1.8.0_102 along with its JRE.  In Eclipse Mars.2 (4.5.2) when I go to project settings for a project created before I installed JDK 1.8.0_102, I see that the current JRE (for that project) is 1.8.0_20.  This is expected.  When I attempt to select a different JRE (I want to use 1.8.0_102), I see this list:

[image]

So, with JRE 1.8.0_102 I can have compatibility with Java versions 1.2 through 1.7, but if I want compatibility with Java version 1.8, I must pick JRE 1.8.0_20.  How can this be?  Why is there no 1.8.0_102 version that is compatible with Java 1.8?

Comment: Because (iirc) JRE 1.8.9_102 was made before java 1.8, this it can't have compatibilty with it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is because you have 1.8.0_20 set as the JRE to use for this execution environment as an exact match.

In the Preferences open 'Java > Installed JREs > Execution Environments' and select the 'JavaSE-1.8' entry. Change the selected 'compatible JRE' to be the 1.8.0_102 JRE.

The other execution environments probably don't have a explicit JRE selected so they are just using the newest available.